# py2exe Bundle=1 Application Crashes. Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, py2exe

I am having issues packaging my script with py2exe. It works fine with Bundle=3, but I need an application that can run completely stand-alone with no extra files.

System:

- win7x86
- Python 2.7
- Latest py2exe

I use the following libs in my application:
'Tkinter','ttk','time','tkFont','urllib2','md5','sys','os','hid'

This is my setup script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
DATA_FILES = []

APP = [{'script': 'app.py',
        'name': 'app',
        'icon_resources': [(1, 'icon.ico')]
        }]

OPTIONS = {'py2exe':{
'includes':['Tkinter','ttk','time','tkFont','urllib2','md5','sys','os','hid',"encodings", "encodings.*"],
'bundle_files': 1,
'dist_dir': './Win_Build/',
'compressed': 1,
'optimize': 1,
"dll_excludes": ['C:\\Python27\\tcl\\tcl8.5\\init.tcl',"C:\\\\Python27\\DLLs\\tcl85.dll", "C:\\\\Python27\\DLLs\\tk85.dll","C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\*.*"]
}}


setup(
    windows=APP,
zipfile=None,
options=OPTIONS,
data_files=DATA_FILES,
version="2.0.0.0",
)
```

The problem is that when i run the application all i get it "App has stopped working Windows can check online for...."

I have tried multiple different suggestions I've found on the internet, but all either result in a non-stand-alone application and still won't run, or nothing changes at all in the build dir.

Thanks,

EDIT:
I would like to avoid using pyInstaller if possible.

From: [Python py2exe window showing (tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566531/python-py2exe-window-showing-tkinter)

Changed dll excludes, and data_files...

```
"dll_excludes": []
DATA_FILES = ['C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\tcl{0}.dll'.format(TCL_VERSION.replace('.','')),'C:\\Python27\\DLLs\\tk{0}.dll'.format(TK_VERSION.replace('.',''))]
```

Unfortunately this has no effect.

Answer (score 3):

in the link is written:
Add "dll_excludes": ["tcl85.dll", "tk85.dll"]
and copy dll manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot this seems to have fixed my problem!

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon, after doing cleanup and rebuilding it no longer works

Comment: i now get the following error: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module

  File "Tkinter.pyc", line 38, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module

  File "FixTk.pyc", line 65, in <module>

  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 98, in load_module

ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading _tkinter.pyd`

Comment: is there anyway to properly include "tcl85.dll", "tk85.dll" so the program can actually be stand alone as that is the point of py2exe?