# Nothing shows when running Tkinter py2exe file

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, py2exe

I have written an application based on Tkinter which is summarized below:

```
import ttk
import Tkinter as tk

class MyFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        # program code here


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MyFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works fine when running the code through the interpreter. I then compile an exe file with py2exe like so:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}} 

setup( windows=["crve.py"], zipfile = None, options = options)
```

This seems to work fine, with all the files showing up as they should and so on. But when I run the exe file, the mouse pointer shows that the computer is working on something for a few seconds but nothing shows up on the screen.

I have tried searching this and other forums for a solution to no avail. How can I solve this problem? I have no error code to look for either. Your help is much appreciated.

Edit 1:
Some clarification is in order. I am using python 2.7 and the corresponding version of py2win. I run py2exe from cmd using the command:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Edit 2:
The problem has been solved thanks to Arden's suggested reading. The solution was to exclude two dll's by adding:

```
options = {'py2exe': {"dll_excludes": ["tcl85.dll", "tk85.dll"]}}
```

And then copying the files manually from the python_path/dlls.

Comment: I've never used py2exe, but are you certain that `__name__ == '__main__'` is True when you run the exe? Perhaps `__name__` is set to something else.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Thank you for the comment. I tried replacing the last part with:
`root = tk.Tk()
app = MyFrame(root)
root.mainloop()`
Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you running py2exe to install? This problem isn't with tkinter, i ran your example on python3 using

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

it gave me a helpful error. It stated that i needed to change the bundle_files option to 2 to work with tkinter.

Comment: Did you get it to run after correcting the error? I changed to `bundle_files: 2` but it still does nothing. I run `python setup.py py2exe` from cmd after changing directory to my working directory. I should have been more clear about this, thank you for pointing it out. And I am using python 2.7.

Comment: yes it ran fine on python3, didn't work on python2 though, this question looks like it has your solution -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566531/python-py2exe-window-showing-tkinter

Comment: Yes, I tried excluding the dll's suggested in your linked topic, and it seems to work now! Thank you a lot!