# Py2Exe TkInter: DLL load failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, py2exe

I used py2exe to create compile my Python 3.4 script. It runs fine on the PC I compiled it on (Windows 10 64 bit), however when I try to run it on another PC which doesn't have Python installed (Windows 7 64 bit), I get the following error in the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PCSpeedDiagnostics.pyw", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\_fix.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 8, in __load
ImportError: (DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.) 'C:\\Users\\[MY NAME]\\Downloads\\dist\\_tkinter.pyd'
```

The _tkinter.pyd file is in fact included in the directory where it apparently cannot be found.

Below is my setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, tkinter

setup(windows=['PCSpeedDiagnostics.pyw'],
    name="PC Speed Diagnostics Tool",
    data_files = [('', ['banner.png', 'blank.png', 'dialog_apply.png',
                        'gnome_application_x_executable.png', 'gnome_dialog_error.png',
                        'gnome_document_send.png', 'gnome_document_send_error.png',
                        'gnome_network_offline.png', 'gnome_network_transmit_receive.png',
                        'gnome_network_wireless.png', 'gnome_system_run.png',
                        'iperf3.exe'])],
    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'bundle_files': 3,
            'optimize': 2,
            'includes': ['tkinter'],
        }
    },
)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14566647/963265, I now have the answer.

This is my new setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, tkinter

setup(windows=['PCSpeedDiagnostics.pyw'],
    name="PC Speed Diagnostics Tool",
    data_files = [('', ['banner.png', 'blank.png', 'dialog_apply.png',
                        'gnome_application_x_executable.png', 'gnome_dialog_error.png',
                        'gnome_document_send.png', 'gnome_document_send_error.png',
                        'gnome_network_offline.png', 'gnome_network_transmit_receive.png',
                        'gnome_network_wireless.png', 'gnome_system_run.png',
                        'tcl86.dll', 'tk86.dll', 'iperf3.exe'])],
    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'bundle_files': 3,
            'optimize': 1,
            'includes': ['tkinter'],
            'dll_excludes': ['tcl86.dll', 'tk86.dll'],
        }
    },
)
```

and I have copied tcl86.dll and tk86.dll into the same directory as the exe.